# db_owner cannot create table in Schema

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2008-r2, create-table

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2. I am a member of the `db_owner` fixed role.

I created a new schema :

```
CREATE SCHEMA [DLIFE] AUTHORIZATION [myLoginID]
```

I have also successfully created several views within that schema.

However, now I am trying to create a new table in the above schema:

```
CREATE TABLE DLIFE.ABCD(Field1 nvarchar(100) null)
```

.. and I get this err :

> Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find the object "dbo.ABCD" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

For the life of me I cannot see what the problem could be !?

I've gone into object explorer, navigated to schemas, DLIFE, entered my login, and it says that I have effective permission for `ALTER`. Also checked DB permissions and I have `CREATE TABLE`.

I can also create tables on dbo, just not new schemas that I create.

Anyone point me in the right direction here ?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: What do you have in "owned schemas" in the security property window?

Comment: Against the Schemas that I created myself, it is neither a tick or unticked... the tickbox is filled in blue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error !

It was some poor code in a database trigger.
The trigger was FOR CREATE TABLE, and had a 'dbo' hard coded in there.

So in many ways I apologise for the false lead.
However, hope it may help someone who makes the same mistake in the future ;)